# Windows 7, Can't execute commands without their extension anymore

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

Since a recent update of Windows 7, I'm facing a weird probleme which I never faced before. All my environment variables are up to date, but, all my commands need the extension to execute. 
For example, this works :

```
git.exe commit && node.exe
```

This doesn't work :

```
git commit && node
```

Commands without extensions seems to not be detected anymore. 
I tried to change registry like it's explained here,

[itprotoday](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-78/how-do-i-enabledisable-command-extensions)

Didn't work. Tried a lot of things without success ...

Some one have an idea?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Cannot Run Programs Without Typing the Extension (.EXE) in Command Prompt](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-cannot-run-programs-without-typing-extension-exe-command-prompt/)

- Press WinKey + R, type `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` and press ENTER

  > **Note:** If the above command doesn't work on Windows 7, then launch the dialog by running:
  >
  > **Sysdm.cpl** → Advanced → Environment Variables
- Click Environment Variables, and double-click PATHEXT
- Set the PATHEXT value, as follows:

  > .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

Comment: Thank you so much ! That's the solution !